# Incorporating external changes using Mercurial and TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, branch, tortoisehg

I'm looking for advice on how best to organize my repository to handle outside changes.  And, I have a simple user question on creating a branch in TortoiseHg.  This is my first time setting this sort of thing up, so I'm having trouble figuring out the most straightforward way to handle it.

I have a website set up on a service.  The theme we're using is based on one of their examples.  Occasionally, they'll update the theme we're based on.  And, most of the time, I would like to incorporate most of those changes.

The part that is tripping me up is that I don't necessarily want to incorporate all of their changes.  So, is the correct way to do it to create two branches?  One that is canonical version, straight from them, containing only their edits?  And the other is our release branch, that we merge in only portions of their changes?

Will the canonical branch persist?  Or, does it come into existence only when they do a new dump, and then I do a manual merge back into my release branch with the changes I want to incorporate?

If it's persistent, is there some way to use TortoiseHg to create the branch back at the root?  Or, do I need to dig into the command-line syntax to do that?  I know this is a one-time thing for this project.  But, I'm looking for advice on how to do this in other software situations, where I want to go back to an earlier version to make a patch.  I'm sure there's a tutorial for exactly this situation, but I wasn't able to come up with the correct search phrase to find it.  At least, not using TortoiseHg.

Answer (score 0):

If upstream theme is also version-controlled (in *any* SCM, supported by Mercurial), two long-term branches with grafting some subset of changesets from `VENDOR` to `MY` is, naturally, fast and easy way (another possible solution is MQ-patches on top of branch with vanilla theme, but it's *slightly* harder way)

If original theme not versioned, you can just grab sources from time to time, edit (incorporate own changes, remove unwanted) and commit this own changeset into single-branch repository

> is there some way to use TortoiseHg to create the branch back at the root?

I can not recall or find (with quick-search) *nice & obvious* way to create branch in GUI-way (i.e. big button on toolbar "Branch"), but you can create branch at commit stage (anyway, branch doesn't exist while at least one changeset in this branch isn't committed). In order to create branch, starting from `<some old>` changeset, you have:

- Update to `<some old>` changeset (RClick - `Update...`)
- Commit (without changing anything), but in commit dialogue use "Branch" button on commit-toolbar (see `1`) in order to change old branch-name to some new (see `2`)

[image: New Branch in THG]